# WooCommerce Subscriptions Extension: Add Frequency

Tags: woocommerce

I am new to WordPress Plugin development:
I am using WooCommerce Subscriptions Extension. I have a requirement of Initiating the subscription every weekday. So my thought was to include Every (Weekday, Monday, Tues, Wed, Thur,Fri, Sat, Sunday)  frequency Options. Currently, its ( day, week, month, year). I dont want to touch existing.  I am going through Documentation, but not getting any clue where to start.

Or should i add the logic where Order is getting created during everyday subscription?

Comment: It's unclear to me how this is different from the daily "day" option. Can you please clarify?

Comment: ex: I want to schedule this only weekday,, Or Want to schedule only on weekends, Or Particualr subscription is only available on Monday.
apart from that, i am planning to add some exclude list as well like, Subscription should create order for new year, Feb28th etc..